# Keyboard stops responding 5 seconds after waking from sleep

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard

I have been using my trusty HP Pavillion DV5-1251NR Entertainment Notebook PC for more than a year now. I had been using Windows XP x86 on it before switching over to Windows 7 x86 about nine months back. Since two months, however, I’ve started having this issue.

When I close the lid / press sleep button to put the notebook on sleep, and then try to wake it up, the keyboard works for about 5 seconds before dying – the keyboard isn’t dead.

I can wake the notebook by lifting the lid, pressing the power button, moving the mouse, or pressing any key as well, but it works just for a few seconds before dying. After that it doesn’t work unless i restart the system or hibernate and then resume it.

What could be the problem? I was able to use the sleep function without problems before. Now I have to change power plans to forbid sleeping at all.

EDIT:
It may be worth mentioning that I've tried the following potential solutions. I'll keep updating if they work or not.

**FIXING DEVICE MANAGER SETTINGS**

My device manager shows the following entries under **Keyboard** and **Universal Serial Bus Controllers**. For all entries that allowed me to perform power management on them, I've ensured that the *Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power* option is unchecked.

1. HID Keyboard Device (doesnt show power management tab)
2. Standard PS/2 Keyboard
3. USB Root Hub

Answer (score 0):

I would start troubleshooting in the Device Manager (Control Panel --> System)  What you are looking for is the Keyboard, then Power Management tab.

I would also be fascinated to know what happens if you wiggle the mouse instead of pressing the keyboard when attempting to wake the laptop.

Next I would check the Power Management settings (Control Panel, Hardware, Power Options).  If you have not used them before they are fiendish to change, you have to remember Changed advance power options.  It always takes me a few goes to get any changes to 'stick'.

My point there are few places where you can change Power Management settings, by checking you may see a fault, or something that you can change to get the behaviour you desire.

Comment: ive edited the question to include the details out the Device Manager console.. also, wiggling the mouse to wake the notebook up has the same result.. the keyboard works for a few seconds before dying.. the only working workaround for me is to either hibernate and then resume, restart, or disable sleep completely.. none of which is practical..

Comment: My HID Keyboard has a Power Management tab.  A slim chance that update driver will deliver such a tab and cure the problem.

Comment: tried that.. =S.. no software update for keyboard for my notebook.. never was.. and it used to work fine till about 3 months ago.. thats what bothers me.. why would it start giving problems all of a sudden? ive tried reinstalling windows7 from scratch a couple of times.. with the same result.. that waking from sleep causes keyboard to die after a few seconds..

Comment: Bump! Does anybody know how to resolve this issue? =S